# Rsyslog + Nginx. Настройка конечного файла

Tags: nginx, rsyslog

настраиваю связку Rsyslog + Nginx. Все замечательно работает, на сервере создается папка в ней файл и именем программы **nginx.log**. Но на сервере на котором крутится Nginx более 20 доменных имен находится. Подскажите если возможность на сервере получать файл с именем доменна на который был сделан запрос.

**Настройка Nginx**

```
upstream blatest {
    server XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;
}

server {
    server_name  bla.example.ru;

    root   /var/www/html;
    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;

        proxy_pass              http://blatest;
    }
     access_log syslog:server=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:514,facility=local7,tag=nginx,severity=debug;
     error_log syslog:server=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:514,facility=local7,tag=nginx,severity=error;
```

**Настройка Rsyslog**

```
module(load="imtcp")
input(type="imtcp" port="514")
#$template RemoteLogs,"/syslogs/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"
*.* ?RemoteLogs
```

Вот как мне на сервере Rsyslog получить файл с именем **bla.example.ru.access.log** и **bla.example.ru.error.log**
А не просто **nginx.log**

В [официальной документации](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/configuration/properties.html) нет такой возможности, вдруг кто знает костыльный метод.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение, оказывается что **tag=nginx** он и формирует имя файла. Если **tag=example_bla_bla_ru** то конечный файл будет называться **example_bla_bla_ru.log**
Данное поле пропускает только Алфавит и подчеркивание